# How to draw arrows and arcs in a contour plot using Python matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, shapes

I have made a contour plot like that using Python Matplot lib

[image: Picture from Google]

I would like to know how can I add arrows like those white ones, and something like this little arc on bellow the angle theta (to show the angle)

It wold be really helpful

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `pyplot.annotate()`. [Here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/annotation_demo.html) is a tutorial with example code.